# Can't install Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL in my .NET 7 app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I was following the next video to add support for EF with PostgreSQL:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRxG9ORD7Hk

Yet, I got the next results while trying this `dotnet add package` cmd:

```
#dotnet add package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing /tmp/tmpbRFUdc.tmp
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the fallback certificate bundle at '/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/7.0.112/trustedroots/codesignctl.pem'.
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the fallback certificate bundle at '/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/7.0.112/trustedroots/timestampctl.pem'.
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' into project '/application/gitCola/vivo_prof_editor/vivo_prof_editor.csproj'.
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/npgsql.entityframeworkcore.postgresql/index.json
info : Restoring packages for /application/gitCola/vivo_prof_editor/vivo_prof_editor.csproj...
error: NU1202: Package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 8.0.0 is not compatible with net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0). Package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 8.0.0 supports: net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
error: Package 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project '/application/gitCola/vivo_prof_editor/vivo_prof_editor.csproj'.
root@32e183e2b6e8:/application/gitCola/vivo_prof_editor#
```

I am using .NET 7 so I suppose this "add package" cmd tries to install for .NET 8 by default. How can I restrict it to .NET 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the version of the nuget package you are installing in the command like below:

`dotnet add package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL --version 7.0.11`

[7.0.11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/7.0.11#supportedframeworks-body-tab): This is the latest version of the package that supports .Net7